# How to use JSON with Python

Tags: python, json, server

I have a problem with my JSON file, I fill the json with a web server python but I tried to put square brackets ( [] ) in the json file and to put a comma ( , ) at the end of each object. The brackets open well, the commas open well but the closing bracket does not want to open.
If anyone knows how to help me.

```
from asyncio import tasks
import json
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, url_for, request
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse
#from jinja2 import Markup

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('task')

class TodoResource(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {'tasks': tasks}

    def post(self):
        args = parser.parse_args()
        task = {'task': args['task']}
        tasks.append(task)
        return task, 201

api.add_resource(TodoResource, '/tasks')

@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.form
        with open("./data.json", "a") as f:
            if f.tell() == 0:
                f.write("[\n")
            else:
                f.write(",\n")
            json.dump(data, f)

    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/end', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def end():
    with open("./data.json", "r+") as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        f.seek(0)
        f.write("[")
        for i, obj in enumerate(data):
            if i != 0:
                f.write(",")
            json.dump(obj, f)
        f.write("\n]")
        f.flush()
        os.fsync(f.fileno())

    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/data')
def get_data():
    with open('data.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    return jsonify(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #app.run(debug=True)
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

and this is my Json file:

```
[
{"alley": "B", "row": "C", "height": "0"},
{"alley": "A", "row": "A", "height": "0"},
{"alley": "D", "row": "B", "height": "3"},
{"alley": "B", "row": "C", "height": "3"},
{"alley": "", "row": "", "height": ""},
{"alley": "B", "row": "A", "height": "1"},
{"alley": "B", "row": "A", "height": "1"},
{"alley": "C", "row": "C", "height": "0"}
```

Like you can see I've the open bracket and the commas but I don't have the end bracket.

I try it but didn't work:

```
@app.route('/end', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def end():
    with open("./data.json", "r+") as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        f.seek(0)
        f.write("[")
        for i, obj in enumerate(data):
            if i != 0:
                f.write(",")
            json.dump(obj, f)
        f.write("\n]")
        f.flush()
        os.fsync(f.fileno())
```

The 2 last ligne, I try to force to write.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I see two endpoints, one for `/` and one for `/end`. The endpoint for `/` never writes a closing bracket:

```
@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.form
        with open("./data.json", "a") as f:
            if f.tell() == 0:
                f.write("[\n")
            else:
                f.write(",\n")
            json.dump(data, f)
            # f.write("\n]") # <<< This line is missing.

    return render_template('home.html')
```

Perhaps the results you're seeing are from the first endpoint? In that case, add the commented-out line above.

Comment: Ok thanks now I have the last hook added but I have a new problem, now it is added at each end of the object but I want it to be only on the last:                                                       [
{"alley": "B", "row": "C", "height": "0"}
],
{"alley": "A", "row": "A", "height": "2"}
],
{"alley": "D", "row": "C", "height": "0"}
],
{"alley": "D", "row": "C", "height": "0"}
],
{"alley": "B", "row": "A", "height": "0"}
]